# Send query to result page from custom search box

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts

How shall I send my query from search box to result page if below is my code in react js:

```
this._handleSearch.bind(this)


 <SearchBox
        styles={searchBoxStyles}
        placeholder="Search"
        onEscape={ev => {
          console.log('Custom onEscape Called');
        }}
        onClear={ev => {
          console.log('Custom onClear Called');
        }}
        onChange={(_, newValue) => console.log('SearchBox onChange fired: ' + newValue)}
        onSearch={newValue => this._handleSearch.bind(this)}
      />
```

Comment: Check code given here: https://github.com/VelinGeorgiev/spfx-react-search-box-webpart/blob/master/src/webparts/reactSearchBox/components/ReactSearchBox.tsx. Let me know if this works for you and I will add as an answer below.

Comment: it worked but it always send object object in search query

Comment: Probably you are passing whole object/array to query. You have to pass single property (like text property) to result page URL. Can you add current code in _handleSearch function to original question?

Comment: is something related to onChange event

Comment: You can update `state` in onChange event & use it to pass to result page URL as shown in above link OR directly pass `newValue` to `_handleSearch` function from `onSearch` property and use it to pass to result page URL.

Comment: onSearch={newValue =>this._handleSearch.bind(newValue)} is it correct

Comment: thanks for help it worked

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update state in `onChange` event of `SearchBox` and use updated state property to pass to result page URL as shown in this web part sample:

[ReactSearchBox.tsx](https://github.com/VelinGeorgiev/spfx-react-search-box-webpart/blob/master/src/webparts/reactSearchBox/components/ReactSearchBox.tsx)

**OR** directly pass `newValue` to `_handleSearch()` function from `onSearch` property of `SearchBox` and use it to pass to result page URL.

**Code from above link**:

SearchBox control:

```
<SearchBox
  className="react-search-box"
  onChange={this._handleInputChange.bind(this)}
  onSearch={this._handleSearch.bind(this)}>
</SearchBox>
```

`_handleSearch` function:

```
/**
* Search button event handler.
* @param event 
*/
private _handleSearch(event: any): void {

    // if a page is specified in the search page results url property 
    // then use it instead of the enterprise search results page.
    if (this.props.searchResultsPageUrl) {

      this.ResultsPageUri = this.props.searchResultsPageUrl;

    } else {

      // defaults to the enterprise search results page.
      this.ResultsPageUri = `${this.props.tenantUrl}/search/Pages/results.aspx`;
    }

    // append the query string to the url.
    this.ResultsPageUri += `?k=${this.state.searchQuery}`;
    this._redirect();
}
```

`_handleInputChange` function:

```
/**
* Search input handler.
* @param searchQuery
*/
private _handleInputChange(searchQuery: string): void {

    this.setState((prevState: IReactSearchBoxState, props: IReactSearchBoxProps): IReactSearchBoxState => {
      prevState.searchQuery = searchQuery;
      return prevState;
    });
}
```